# Is PHPUnit ordering by "all defects" or "recent defects"?

Tags: phpunit

When I run PHPUnit 7 with the `--order-by=defects` flag should I expect my tests to be sorted by:

all-time defectiveness (e.g., I've had a lot of failures in module Foo, so even if I'm working in Bar today it'll run Foo first)

recent defectiveness (e.g. I just wrote a red test in new module Baz, so it'll run Baz first, even before the legendarily failure-prone Foo)